# How to print numbers based on user inputted integer in java?

Tags: java, for-loop

I need help in writing code in Java which takes in user-input ("x" for integer then prints numbers from 1 onward to the "x". Then, on the next line, it increments once and prints "x" more numbers again for "x" number of times. I tried to use nested for-loops for it. Below is how the output should be:

If the user enters 4, the output should be:

```
1234
2345
4567
5678
```

If the user inputs 5 then:

```
12345
23456
34567
45678
56789
```

Here is the code I have written so far:

```java
// start of code
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    int x = in.nextInt();  // initial number entered by user to repeat it

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        int j = i + 1;

        for (int a = j; a <= j; a++) {
            // System.out.println();
            System.out.print(a + " ");
        }
    }

}  // end of main
```

Thanks for the reading my question, this is my first time posting a question here, so I am still new to posting code here. Hopefully I did it properly.

Comment: Does your code work? Does it compile? Does it print the wrong result? Does it throw an exception? Don't make us guess what you're asking.

Comment: Yes the code compiles and the output was: 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6, for the user-inputted "5"

Comment: How many times do you think `for (int a = j; a <= j; a++)` will iterate?

Comment: Rename your loop variables from `i` to `startingNumber` and `j` to `delta`, remove the first print, and print `startingNumber + delta` and you'll be close

Comment: I think technically it should iterate 10 times as the original first for-loop goes 5 times, then second should do it 5 more. I'm not sure as I'm not too good at nested for-loops. I had first tried to include that second for loop outside the first loop but it didn't compile because it didn't recognize what 'j' was. I intended this line: "int j = i + 1" to increase by 1 every line onwards when it repeats the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to test the code right now, but I think you are looking something similar to this.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < x+i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

You just have to change your nested loop for the one I wrote

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are looking for. but here is what I understand:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    int x = in.nextInt(); //initial number entered by user to repeat it

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        int j = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(j);
    }

}
```